# Is it preferrable to use character codes in html for special characters or the character itself?

Tags: html, special-characters

I have an html file with the character `ë` in it.

The html contains this line, which specifies that I'm using the iso-8859-15 character set.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">`

I can choose between using the character code `&euml;` or the character `ë` itself in the html file. Both work just fine.

I was wondering whether one is preferrable over the other and why?

Comment: The only situation where `&euml;` would objectively be preferable is when your material ends up in a situation where your meta tag isn't recognised, for instance when you paste your whole page into an email, or if your server decides to start sending an encoding in its HTTP header. Otherwise, it's a matter of opinion; not going there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real characters are:

- More bandwidth efficient
- Easier to read when you are writing or editing your pages

Entities:

- Save you from having to care so much about character encoding

Just use real characters and make sure you have a single unicode encoding through your entire production chain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the character code ensures the greatest amout of reusability/flexibility. For example, If I ever wanted to copy and paste that text somewhere where I haven't defined the charset, it's more likely to work. In addition, if the content is coming from a DB, it ensures the greatest amount of flexibility.

Disclaimer: There is no right answer to this question - it's purely opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> Entities are used to implement reserved characters or to express
>   characters that cannot easily be entered with the keyboard.

So I think it's better to use entity name `&euml` or entity number `&#235;`.

Comment: What is the source of your quote, and why does this quote imply that html entities are better?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ISO-8859-15, as it is less widely supported than ISO-8859-1 and offers no real benefits over it even when it works. If you use entities, end them with semicolons: `&euml;` (not `&euml`).

Regarding the use of characters vs. entity references, perhaps the best answer is: if you have to ask, use entities. But using characters as such isn’t really rocket science, and it keeps the source much more readable.

Comment: The choice for using ISO-8859-15 is not mine. The missing semicolon is just a typo. I know this is not rocket science, I'm just curious about the practical differences between the two.